# What do I need to make TNT?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I make TNT?
Where do I get the things I need to make TNT?
How do I get the things I need to make TNT?
I can't find any pitching other than the sand needed to make TNT.

Comment: For future reference, anything that can easily be found by doing a quick search on the Minecraft wiki will not be well received here.  Please do at least some research before asking.

Comment: @MBraedley which is strange because we often say to summarize external links so the answer stands on it's own when the site goes down. So this is actually an excellent question because you never know when the wiki get's a DDoS attacked ;).

Comment: @MennoGouw but what if *this* site gets DDoSed as well?...We need a third site to summarise the answers on this site!

Answer (score 17):

TNT requires 4 Sand and 5 Gunpowder, arranged in this pattern:

[image: Recipe for TNT]

Sand can be found and dug up like any other block, especially in Desert biomes or along beaches.

Gunpowder you can get from a few different places:

1. **Creepers**

- Probably the easiest method. You have to actually kill them, not allow them to blow up by themselves
- They have a chance of dropping up to 2 pieces of gunpowder upon death

2. **Ghasts** (Nether)

- They have a chance of dropping up to 2 pieces of gunpowder upon death.

3. **Chests**

- Gunpowder has a 1 in 12 chance of spawning in a dungeon chest, where it will appear in stacks of 1 to 4

4. **Witches**

- Witches were introduced in Minecraft Release v1.4.2
- they have a 1 in 8 chance of dropping up to 6 pieces of gunpowder upon death

###Source - Minecraft Wiki:

- [TNT](https://minecraft.wiki/w/TNT)
- [Witches](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Witch)
- [Gunpowder](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Gunpowder)

Comment: adding onto this answer, Sand can be found and dug up, gunpowder you have to kill Creapers, you have to kill them and not just hit them and let them explode

Comment: You don't *have* to kill creepers, although they are the most plentiful and renewable source of it. Ghasts also drop gunpowder (When they don't drop it into a sea of lava), and it can be obtained in small quantities from dungeon chests.

Comment: @Memor-X feel free to add that to my answer!

Comment: Updated answer with some new info :)